# How to define a \newparencite producing year before author in the authoryear-comp style?

Tags: biblatex, authoryear-comp, parencite

First an MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{jensen1916,
    AUTHOR = {A. Jensen and B. Bonus and N. Loretan and D. Yong},
    TITLE = {Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Maal og Minne},
    YEAR = {1916},
    NUMBER = {1--2},
    PAGES = {60--89}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite{jensen1916}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the `\parencite` produces author before year. *Then how to define a `\newparencite` producing year before author while acting the same as `\parencite` in other aspects, for example the hyper links?*

With such `\newparencite` we could have texts as follows.

1. (1916 Jensen) ....
2. (1981, 2010 Knuth) ....
3. (2020 Green) ...

Comment: Do you need your new command to also take into account the "comp" behaviour? That is to say do you want to get "1984, 1986 Knuth" if you cite two works by Knuth? (That would make things *much* harder: If we place the name first, it is easy to omit the name if it is the same as the previous name. But now we need to omit the name if it is the same as the following name, which we haven't seen yet.)

Comment: This is just to satisfy my curiosity: But *why* do you want such a reversed order of year and author? Is it common in some fields of study? I have never seen such a citation style before.

Comment: Yes, your are right, like "1984, 1986 Knuth". I want to give an introduction to some books according to years, and that would be more uniform in view if the years are in the front.

Comment: OK, as I said, that is going to be slightly more difficult. I'm going to see what I can do when I have time for a "larger" project.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot.